# Form is Not Posting data

Tags: html, forms, post, http-status-code-302

Form is Not Posting data it redirects to homepage

I'm using *tinymce* plugin which bind to text-area when i submit form it send html code data e.g.

```
<p>hello</p>
```

like this as soon as post the data it go to main home page of the website and error show while posting is 302 found. when i submit non-html data it's successfully submitted e.g.

```
Hello
```

same problem in GET method

Comment: Can you post your `<form>` html please?

Comment: <form action="jobs.php" method="post">